# Can someone please explain how to use Date Dialog Fragment to send data back to parent Fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment, dialogfragment

it'd be great if someone provide an example on implementation of Date DialogFragment. I'm a complete beginner to android programming and stucked in one of the tutorial in which DatePicker dialog fragment is used since the .setTargetFragment() is deprecated. I would like to see how is it done alternatively.